# thumbnail SonataMediaBundle

Tags: symfony, thumbnails, sonata-media-bundle

What is the meaning of thumbnail in SonataMediaBundle, it's an image, image in cache, image resized ? especially in template :

What is the difference between 
Render the thumbnail:

```
{% thumbnail media, 'small' %}
```

and :

```
{% media media, 'small' %}
```

It render the same thing, i.e an image !

Thnaks !

Comment: In {% thumbnail media, 'small' %} 'media' is a object , and it may be any type like 'video','audio' or 'image' , 'thumbnail' will show the just first look of that 'media' object as 'image' format , while in {% media media 'small' %} both the 'media' will be in the same format either 'video', 'audio' or 'image' ... format, i means rendering will be in the not only in 'image' format but also will be in 'video' or 'audio' etc ..

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand this kind of doubts is to give a look to the source code;

**media**
https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/blob/master/Twig/Extension/MediaExtension.php#L69

**thumbnail**
https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/blob/master/Twig/Extension/MediaExtension.php#L123

and the **templates**:
https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Provider/thumbnail.html.twig

As you can see from templates folder:
 **thumbnail.html.twig**

```
<img {% for name, value in options %}{{name}}="{{value}}" {% endfor %} />
```

the thumbnail extension show the thumbnail image for a media

instead based on the media you want view, the media extension will load the appropriate template (view_dailymotion.html.twig, view_file.html.twig, view_image.html.twig, view_vimeo.html.twig, view_youtube.html.twig) that will show the "real" media

If the media is a picture you will have the same result for both

```
{% thumbnail media, 'small' %}
```

and

```
{% media media, 'small' %}
```

The template for **view_image.html.twig** is in fact:

```
<img {% for name, value in options %}{{ name }}="{{ value }}" {% endfor %} />
```

Instead if the media is a youtube media
 **view_youtube.html.twig**

```
{% if options.html5 %}
    <iframe width="{{ options.player_parameters.width }}" height="{{ options.player_parameters.height }}" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/{{ media.providerreference }}?{{ options.player_url_parameters }}" frameborder="{{ options.player_parameters.border }}"{% if options.player_parameters.allowFullScreen %} allowfullscreen{% endif %}></iframe>
{% else %}
    {% if options.player_parameters.allowFullScreen %}
        {% set allowFullScreen = "true" %}
    {% else %}
        {% set allowFullScreen = "false" %}
    {% endif %}
    <object width="{{ options.player_parameters.width }}" height="{{ options.player_parameters.height }}">
        <param name="movie" value="//www.youtube.com/v/{{ media.providerreference }}?{{ options.player_url_parameters }}"></param>
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="{{ allowFullScreen }}"></param>
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="{{ options.player_parameters.allowScriptAccess }}"></param>
        <param name="wmode" value="{{ options.player_parameters.wmode}}">

        <embed
            src="//www.youtube.com/v/{{ media.providerreference }}?{{ options.player_url_parameters }}"
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
            allowscriptaccess="{{ options.player_parameters.allowScriptAccess }}"
            allowfullscreen="{{ allowFullScreen }}"
            width="{{ options.player_parameters.width }}"
            height="{{ options.player_parameters.height }}"
            wmode="{{options.player_parameters.wmode}}">
        </embed>
    </object>
{% endif %}
```